# How to print result of clustering in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a sparse matrix

```
from scipy.sparse import *
M = csr_matrix((data_np, (rows_np, columns_np)));
```

then I'm doing clustering that way

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=n, init='random', max_iter=100, n_init=1, verbose=1)
km.fit(M)
```

and my question is extremely noob: how to print the clustering result without any extra information. I don't care about plotting or distances. I just need clustered rows looking that way

```
Cluster 1
row 1
row 2
row 3

Cluster 2
row 4
row 20
row 1000
...
```

How can I get it? Excuse me for this question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Time to help myself. After

```
km.fit(M)
```

we run

```
labels = km.predict(M)
```

which returns **labels**, numpy.ndarray. Number of elements in this array equals number of rows. And each element means that a row belongs to the cluster.
For example: if first element is 5 it means that row 1 belongs to cluster 5.
Lets put our rows in a dictionary of lists looking this way {cluster_number:[row1, row2, row3], ...}

```
# in row_dict we store actual meanings of rows, in my case it's russian words
clusters = {}
    n = 0
    for item in labels:
        if item in clusters:
            clusters[item].append(row_dict[n])
        else:
            clusters[item] = [row_dict[n]]
        n +=1
```

and print the result

```
for item in clusters:
    print "Cluster ", item
    for i in clusters[item]:
        print i
```

Comment: thanks so much, open my mind too :) very helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Update:
You can do it the following way

```
"""data= data clustered retrieved by function as you want"""
"""model = result from the data with got by KMeans"""
"""cluster = clusters formed by the model"""
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data = clusteredData()
model = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='random', max_iter=100, n_init=1, verbose=1)
cluster = model.fit_predict(scale(data))

dictionary = {}
for index in range(len(data)): 
    if cluster[index] in dictionary:
        value = []
        value = dictionary[cluster[index]]
        value.append(data[index])
        dictionary[cluster[index]] = value
    else:
        dictionary[cluster[index]]=data[index]
```

This will create you a dictionary with the NUMBER_OF_THE_CLUSTER as a key and the data within that cluster as a VALUE