# Get values from K-Means clusters using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, k-means

I have this dataframe (text_df):

[image]

There are 10 different authors with 13834 rows of text.

I then created a bag of words and used a TfidfVectorizer like so:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_v = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5,
                          max_features=13000,
                          min_df=5,
                          stop_words='english',
                          use_idf=True,
                          norm=u'l2',
                          smooth_idf=True
                          )

X = tfidf_v.fit_transform(corpus).toarray() # corpus --> bagofwords
y = text_df.iloc[:,1].values
```

Shape of X is (13834,2701)

I decided to use 7 clusters for KMeans:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=7,random_state=42)
```

I'd like to extract the authors of the texts in each cluster to see if the authors are consistently grouped into the same cluster. Not sure about the best way to go about this. Thanks!

**Update:**

Trying to visualize the author count per cluster using nested dictionary like so:

```
author_cluster = {}
for i in range(len(y_kmeans)):
    # check 20 random predictions
    j = np.random.randint(0, 13833, 1)[0]

    if y_kmeans[j] not in author_cluster:
        author_cluster[y_kmeans[j]] = {}

        if y[j] not in author_cluster[y_kmeans[j]]:
            author_cluster[y_kmeans[j]][y[j]] = 1 
        else:
            author_cluster[y_kmeans[j]][y[j]] += 1
```

Output:

[image]

There should be a larger count per cluster and probably more than one author per cluster. I'd like to use all of the predictions to get a more accurate count instead of using a subset. But open to alternative solutions.

Comment: This is probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29801076/8146556

Comment: If there are 10 different authors, why not 10 clusters? Also, why do KMeans for this? If you have labelled data, why not build a classifier?

Comment: @Sam H. It's for a homework assignment. I'll be using a classifier later on, but for the first half need to use a clustering algorithm. I'm using 7 clusters because I used the elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters.

Comment: @rahlf23 is there an alternative to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

tfidf_v = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5,
                          max_features=13000,
                          min_df=5,
                          stop_words='english',
                          use_idf=True,
                          norm=u'l2',
                          smooth_idf=True
                          )

X = tfidf_v.fit_transform(corpus) # I removed .toarray() - not sure why it was there except maybe for print debugging?
y = text_df.iloc[:,1].values

km = KMeans(n_clusters=7,random_state=42)

model = km.fit(X)
result = model.predict(X)

for i in range(20):
    # check 20 random predictions
    container = np.random.randint(low=0, high=13833, size=1)
    j = container[0]
    print(f'Author {y[j]} wrote {X[j]} and was put in cluster {result[j]}')
```

Comment: What does the j = np.random.randint(0,13833,1)[0] accomplish?

Comment: I broke that line into two lines, and tried to make it more clear. Can you tell what it's doing now?

Comment: No problem! Was this enough to get you there?

Comment: Can you share the data?